# Python assigning two lists in one line

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to declare two lists in the same one-liner? Following code contains two one-liners so you have to loop over `c` twice:

```
c = [1,2,3,4]
a = [ d for d in c if (d % 2 == 0)]
b = [ d for d in c if (d % 2 != 0)]
```

Comment: Only if you don't mind the line being 10 times as ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want ??

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a, b = [d for d in c if (d % 2 == 0)], [d for d in c if (d % 2 != 0)]
```

or how about

```
a, b = [], []
for i in c:
    b.append(i) if i % 2 else a.append(i)
```